# toggle effect horizontal in td using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

In my application has master page. One of the content place holder has design as

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width='170px'> -------td1
             <table>... header label</table>
        </td>
        <td width=85%>--------------td2
        </td>
```

My requirement is

when click on header label td1's width set as 1% and td2's width set as 99% and the page adjust automatically as per width.

when again click the header label the width need to set as original .

how to achive this...

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function () { 
    $('.style1').click(function () {
        $(".style2").slideToggle(); 
    }); 
});

<style type="text/css"> 
    .style1 { width: 182px; } 
    .style2 { width: 99%; } 
</style>
```

Comment: $(function () { $('.style1').click(function () { $(".style2").slideToggle(); }); });<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 182px;
    }
    .style2
    {
        width: 99%;
    }
</style>

Comment: I've put the code in your post

Comment: Why are you using tables for layout? It's considered old school, try using <div>'s or HTML5 tags like <header>

Comment: if possible try to make jsfiddle...

Comment: So, did any of the answers fix it for you? Please choose one of them as the correct answer, or tell us what you think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () { $('.lblStyle').click (function () {$(".style1").slideToggle();}); });

<style type="text/css">
.style1
{
    width: 12%;
}

.lblStyle
{
    width: 99%;
}
```

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr align="center">
    <td valign="top" align="center" class="style1">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 170px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 170px">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgHeader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/RIBO/Images/logo_header.png"
                        Width="170px" Height="80px" Style="display: none;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu_header">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMenuHeader" runat="server" Text="" EnableTheming="false" Width="170px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul class="inner_menu">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="170px" Height="100%">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-image: url(../RIBO/App_Themes/RIBO/Images/hd_menu_bottom.png);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="95%" valign="top" align="left">
        <asp:Label ID="lbldummy" runat="server" Text="Test" CssClass="lblStyle"></asp:Label>
        <iframe runat="server" id="ifrmMainContent" name="ifrmMainContent" src="MyPage.aspx"
            frameborder="0" marginheight="10px" marginwidth="1px" style="overflow: scroll; 
            height: 800px; width: 100%; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"></iframe>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have achieved with the above code. with two styles. Instead of lbldummy how to use image with appropriate arrow marks!(If hide will display right arrow, when want to hide left indicate arrow).